# header and footer column width problem - joomla

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, joomla3.0

I want to style the header after the menu to be the same as the header before the menu.

Here is the page: https://www.nikolay100.com/en/?option=com_rspagebuilder&view=page&id=6

I cannot figure out why the column of the "Language switcher" is displayed so big. I want it to be as small as the one on top.

Also I would like the footer background of the top footer to be displayed in full width of the page. The same as the footer bellow.

Which css styles should I change and how.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Language switcher: the class 'col-md-4' makes the width 33.33%. The html (with inline styling) will have the wanted result.

```html
<div class="col-md-4  duration-500" style="text-align: right;">
  <div id="lang_and_search" style="background-color:#efefef;padding:5px;width: auto;display: inline-block;">
    <div class="rspbld-module" style="padding:5px;">
      <div class="mod-languages">
        <ul class="lang-inline" dir="ltr">
          <li><a href="/bg/"><img src="/media/mod_languages/images/bg.gif" alt="Български" title="Български"></a>
          </li>
          <li class="lang-active">
            <a href="https://www.nikolay100.com/en/?option=com_rspagebuilder&amp;view=page&amp;id=6">
                <img src="/media/mod_languages/images/en.gif" alt="English (UK)" title="English (UK)">   </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

- For the footer, it's because it's within the class 'container'. This has a max-width. Move the footer outside the container.